# Regular Expression for accepting numbers 0 to 9999

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regular expression for only accepting 
0-9999

No spaces, no letters. 
However, "blank"(empty) is allowed.

Comment: Why do you use reg.ex for checking a number?

Comment: A good site to test your regex: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @Frederik Wordenskjold: Because not everyone likes using the `int.TryParse` hammer  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\d?\d?\d?\d?
```

Should do it.

Or more succinctly:

```
\d{0, 4}
```

This works because you're saying "0, 1, 2, or 3 digits", where each digit is 0-9. This allows numbers between 0 and 9999, and nothing else.

Note that it allows leading zeros, i.e. 0004 is a valid number.

Comment: @Coolcoder: do you restrict it to be the whole string (i.e. with start string and end string symbols)?

Comment: No spaces, period. Not at start, not at end , not in the middle. Just a space on its own is also not allowed. However, "blank" (no value) is ok :)

Comment: @Coolcoder, in case my previous comment wasn't clear: `^\d{0,4}$`: restricting the string to be **only** the digits, not just containing them

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
[0-9]{0,4}
```

Answer (score 7):

well, `/\d{0,4}/` is the simplest way, but generally I convert to a number and then do bounds checking

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't want to accept numbers left-padded with zeros.

```
(0|([1-9]\d{0,3}))?
```

Read as zero or one of the following: 0 or a 1-9 followed by a 0 to 3 digit string.

Comment: Shouldn't match a space at all since there is no whitespace anywhere in the expression.  Depending on how you are using it you may need to add matching characters for the start and end of string:  `^(0|([1-9]\d{0,3}))?$`